# How to print some property of a model from collection in Handlebars Template?

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js

I am using a Collection of Models in Backbone application. The requirement is to print only first models attribute in the render function using handlebars template. Is there a way to get first element of collection in handlebars template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only the first model of a collection, you can use `collection.at(0);`.  Pass this into the handlebars template and then access it as you would normally within a handlebars template.

Comment: But I am using Collection as I am looping through its contents uisng #each. And I also need only first element in the same view

Comment: @aliasad I would suggest then passing in to the template something like `{firstModel: collection.at(0), collection: collection}`

Comment: @aliasad: The usual approach with Handlebars is to do the real work in JavaScript so that the template itself is quite simple and nearly logic-free. You could write your own `{{#first_of array}}` helper but that would be overkill for a single use.